# table time conversion nanoseconds to minute

Tags: python, pandas, time, python-fractions

the first table to be converted to minute:

```
Time_sec >>> Time_Min)
362.7313    00:06:02,7
490.669     00:08:10,7
824.5673    00:13:44,6
951.829     00:15:51,8
13.0447     00:00:13,0
13.0678     00:00:13,1
122.5468    00:02:02,5
536.7552    00:08:56,8
811.9501    00:13:32,0
938.1133    00:15:38,1
13809718    00:02:19,0
619.4331    00:10:19,4
1407.5125   00:23:27,5
16290049    00:27:09,0
```

did try like this:

```
df['Time_sec'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time_sec'].datetime.timedelta(seconds =df['time_sec'])
```

but for 1629,049 i get 16:29 what must be 27min an 9sec

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for here. The conversions don't make sense, your question says nanoseconds to minutes, but you use `seconds=` in your coding attempt. You mention 1,620,049 should be 27:09, but the value in the your data is 16,290,049.

Comment: So my questions are: (1) are you trying to convert from seconds or nanoseconds? (2) How do you want to handle something like  16290049 which is over 180 days worth of seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first solution would be to use the apply function to all rows :

```py
df["Time_Min"] = df["Time_Sec"].apply(lambda x: f"{x // 60}:{x % 60}")
```

A second solution (maybe more optimized regarding pandas C implementation) :

```py
df["Time_Min"] = df["Time_Sec"].floordiv(60).map(str) + ":" + df["Time_Sec"].mod(60).map(str)
```